# Adding Command line arguments to project using Msbuild command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is there any to pass command line arguments to solution/project by using Msbuild command line?? So that we can use that arguments in c# code?

Comment: @Sergio : Thanks for replying. Yea i know that but that is when we pass command line arguments at run time. I want to know that how to give arguments to project using  Msbuild command line while building solution from Msbuild command line. Msbuild command line is : "Msbuild.exe" "project path" /t:build

Comment: Do you mean something like a [`#define`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) but not written in code but given in compiler arguments? That would be [`/define:name[;name2]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Entrypoint of project contain void Main with signature (string[] args). Command line arguments stored in string[] array.